# Edit Text set Text not wrapping text to the new Line

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am using an edit Text inside a linear layout. however, I notice that when i am setting text dynamically, the text does not wraps to the next line, rather keeps writing in the same line.

I am using singleLine=false and yet it does not wraps the text to next line.

If,However, I give a default string in the xml attribute text for it, then I can see that the text wraps up to the next line.

Snapshot:

[image: time]

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/crt_act_main_data_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/crt_act_start_txt"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/act_start_time"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/crt_act_start_ed"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

... some more rows here ..
 </LinearLayout>
```

In the code I do:

```
m_stTmEdTxt = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.crt_act_start_ed);
m_stTmEdTxt.setText(someval);
m_stTmEdTxt.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to this after reading about a million StackOverflows and experimenting with every form of XML.

The answer is to not do it in XML. No combination of XML (including the exact XML that maps to the programmatic code below) I tried made the EditText resize if I set the text programmatically. Instead, set everything programmatically, AFTER you call setText(), like so:

```
  myEditText.setText("Really long multiple lines of text should be required to display this entire bit of text. You can test it out if you don't believe me.");
  myEditText.setSingleLine(false);
  myEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);

  //Of particular importance, do not leave out the InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT; it will not work without it!
  myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
  myEditText.setMaxLines(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi add below line to your  tag

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLength="200"
android:maxLines="5"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Change the value accordingly.

Comment: i think other answers are directing in the same direction. however, after trying this the end results are still same !

Comment: is that text length is enough for multiple lines.

Comment: android:maxLength="15" instead of android:maxLength="200". it should work

Comment: I tried that, if i put maxLength to 15 then it chops off the remaining text instead of putting it to the next line !

Comment: can you add android:weight="1" also.

Comment: textMultiLine fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting Input Type to your textView

```
   m_stTmEdTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Try this in XML

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
```

Comment: tried, still the same result ! does not wraps to the next line !

Comment: Still the same results. However, even if it were, my layout I can not use layout_weight=1, as i also have a textview and i am splitting screenspace between both of them. i am just wondering why it is behaving like this !

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line XML's Edittext tag **android:inputType="textMultiLine"** and give padding also.

Comment: isnt it same to singleLine=false ?? However, i tried already with this too but the result is same !

Comment: Both are different. you can remove singleLine=false and add above line.let me know once done.

Comment: I tried it already, both from XML and the code (rajan answer). Still the result is same !

Comment: Please check: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".67"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_back"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp" />

Comment: Checked, it does not shows anything at all in edit text now. i guess because of 0dp width !